# Expressions in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to get a certain expression to work in SSRS. My query pulls up a category, sub category and a count statement grouped by the sub category for tracking incidents. This is my query:

```
SELECT Category, Sub_Category, CAST(Count(incident) AS decimal) As Total_Incidences
FROM service_req
GROUP BY Sub_Category
```

I am trying to break these down into percentages, for example a specific sub category accounts for 67% of a certain main category incidences, and would also like to have a percentage of main categories vs total calls, i.e. 12% of all incidences are from this certain category.

My math is not coming out right when trying to make it work, and I cant figure out the best way to do this. Any suggestions? I know I have to divide the count statement by the sum of all incidences in the subcategory to get that percentage, and all sub category sums by the total incidences to get the first percentage however I am not sure how to use a group by with these expressions (or even if I can) to get this to work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: can you show some sample data and the desired result set, also you will need to add Category in your GROUP BY clause in your present query.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved not in SSRS but rather in the query that returns data. You need 2 separate groupings - one by category, another by category/subcategory combination. Then you can join them like this:

```
SELECT Sub.Category, Sub.Sub_Category, Sub.Total_IncidencesSub*100/Main.Total_IncidencesMain AS Percentage FROM

(SELECT Category, CAST(Count(incident) as DECIMAL) As Total_IncidencesMain
FROM service_req
GROUP BY Category) Main

INNER JOIN

(SELECT Category, Sub_Category, CAST(Count(incident) AS DECIMAL) As Total_IncidencesSub
FROM service_req
GROUP BY Category, Sub_Category) Sub

ON Main.Category = Sub.Category
```

Here is live demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eee07/7